# Twitter API 1.1 Error Code 32 while statuses/update_with_media

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter

I receive an error that i havent been authenticated, but i am. Otherwise i couldn't post a normal Tweet(just text) or use all the GET functions from the Twitter API 1.1.

What i've done:

I have written my own class which **extends** **Zend_Service_Twitter**(Abstraction of the Twitter API, which provides an easy access to the API). I extended it to implement more endpoints of the API. e.g. "statuses/update_with_media". The functionality of these functions is similar to the other functions (first the init(), setting parameter and at the end calling post-function). I have set the EncType in Zend_Http_Client to 'multipart/form-data' as it is documented in the API
.
GET Requests are working fine and GET account/verify_credentials is working, too. But POST occures this Error:

ErrorMessage: Could not authenticate you

ErrorCode: 32

Using

Zend 1.12.5

PHP 5.3.14

---

Example Request:

```
POST /1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
Connection: close
Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Zend_Http_Client
Cookie:twid=u%3D1725343788%7CY611pVKbM7CH6i%2Br1Ni%2BkeuSXfU%3D;_twitter_sess=BAh7CDoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCGmjH4tGAToMY3NyZl9pZCIlMGFlNzY5ZDVh%250AMGQ3OThjNGU5YzE1ZjA3YTZmN2I4ZjM6B2lkIiU4ZWJkNTRhOTNhNjhiMGIz%250ANzZjMzYxMTEyZWU3Y2E2Yg%253D%253D--a632ea1411849916ca5399f9654a241b0a70a17f;guest_id=v1%3A140249344476018229;lang=de;
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8
Authorization: OAuth realm="",oauth_consumer_key="bBmTZTbVaziLelczV7VwqBa1U",oauth_nonce="df79065c315b5ed8d690c92a8016cece",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1402493472",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="1725343788-CxwJ3G6HRl0POkrqz6dl6HZImgFdeSzNucyqNkI",oauth_signature="z%2BuRj%2FEyWbo4ym12uYoQdOob%2Bmc%3D"
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---ZENDHTTPCLIENT-6c7c5ce101c5dcf5f666f17e1a10486b
Content-Length: 71108

-----ZENDHTTPCLIENT-6c7c5ce101c5dcf5f666f17e1a10486b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status"

sorjghkl sdaghl
-----ZENDHTTPCLIENT-6c7c5ce101c5dcf5f666f17e1a10486b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media[]"
..... here is the binary picture (access with the function file_get_contents(realpath($src)))...
```

Comment: Check out these common pitfalls; https://dev.twitter.com/docs/uploading-media

Comment: Ty but i dont see any problem. Maximum file size of my photo is 70.826 Bytes, so no problem.Maximum number of media per status update is 1. Users have a separate, published daily media upload limit that is independent of their unpublished daily status update limits... i dont have tweeted any photo today or yesterday... Picture is .jpg and with the function file_getcontents in raw binary data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I solved my issue.

what the Problem is that the Zend_Oauth_Client prepares the Oauth-Header after all Parameters were set to the Http-Client. So the oauth_signature is being generated on theses Parameters... this seems legit for all other operations but NOT for uploading a picture. So what i have done is that i have overwritten some code from zend to get this behavior:

A new Client, which extends Zend_OAuth_Client where i have overwritten the request method..similar to zends method but without the function-call prepareOauth(). Be carefull with calling parent::request() because now you have to call the request method of the Grandparent.

after this i have created my own method in my extension of the Zend_Service_Twitter where i have overwritten the post()-Method. There i hande the chronology of calling the method prepareOauth()